# Questions with SEO context (instead of SEO advice) are on-topic, right? What about these?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, off-topic

It’s my understanding that questions asking for **SEO advice** are off-topic on Stack Overflow, while questions with a **SEO context** should be on-topic.

It’s "How should I … for SEO" (= SEO advice) versus "[Because of SEO] I want to …" (= SEO context).

"Unfortunately" questions of the latter case are often also tagged with [seo](/questions/tagged/seo), and it seems to me that they are sometimes getting closed (primarily) because of having this tag.

For example, these questions are closed currently:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/21233315/1591669: Although this question references "SEO" in the title and tags, the question itself is about the Canonical link relation, and not about search engines’ interpretation of the Canonical link relation.
- [Can Microdata be applied on any type of HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20880229/1591669): This question is about Microdata, not about search engines’ interpretation of Microdata (although the [initial version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20880229/1) contained the question "Will Google still pick up on this correctly?", this was only an *additional* side question that shouldn’t invalidate the whole question).
- [Setting a different title tag for a URL with a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19914834/1591669): It’s tagged with "SEO", but the OP is asking for a way to accomplish it, not if it should be done or if/how search engines would interpret it.

Was this the right move to close them?

---

Couldn’t this be a simple guideline to decide if a "SEO" tagged question is on-topic?

> Can this question be answered by referencing a standard/specification (instead of a blog post or a search engine’s documentation)?

If yes, it’s probably on-topic. (Well, it would at least apply to those three example questions.)

Or the countercheck:

> Would an answer to this question depend on the (current) behaviour/documentation/support of a search engine web service?

If yes, it’s likely off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine that, if you can ask the same question without mentioning SEO, and still have it be on-topic, then it's on-topic.

Comment: Which whould mean that the three mentioned questions shouldn’t have been closed?